# Can we pre-polulate fields in standard pages using URL hacking in lightning?

Tags: lightning

We are transitioning from classic to lightning and we are using a lot of URL hacks to pre populate standard page fields from List buttons.
Is there any other solution except creating actions, where we can re-use the existing URL hacks somehow?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URL hacks are completely unsupported in Lightning. Creating Quick Actions is the recommended route to replace these buttons, and in many ways it's actually a better solution. Quick Actions are a lot easier to create and maintain than URL hacks, and allow you to prepopulate fields using Predefined Field Values set within the Quick Action setup UI.

Salesforce offers a [conversion tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/convert-javascript-buttons-to-lightning-friendly-alternatives-with-the-lightning-experience-configuration-converter.html) you can try out. It may or may not work with your specific customizations, but if they're compatible, it could be a head start on performing the conversion work.

Comment: Never knew about the conversion tool - thank you for the fantastic link!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, if it fits with your use case, is a component developed by Doug Ayers - the [SFDX Record Create URL Component](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdx-record-create-url-component). This is great if you are wanting to pre-populate fields in a Lightning record creation "dialog" opened from a lightning page where you want to substitute values in via parameters. See [his blog posting](https://douglascayers.com/2018/08/05/legitimate-url-hacking-in-lightning-experience/) about the motivation and use case.